# How to set datepicker on select change?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a very simple problem. But I am unable to resolve the issue.

I want to set datepicker to a input on select change. Also on changing the select to other option the datepicker should be removed and only textbox should be displayed.

This is what I have tried so far

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                    jQuery('#filevalidity').change(function(){
                        var option = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
                        if(option === "MAX_DOWNLOAD_LIMIT")
                        {

                            jQuery('#dlorex').next('input').datepicker("destroy");
                        }
                        if(option === "EXPIRY_DATE")
                        {

                            jQuery('#dlorex').next('input').datepicker({minDate : 1});
                        }
                    });

                });
```

**[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/ktjsyfg0/)**

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` gets the sibling at the same level (in this case, same level as tr)

You can use `find()` to target the `input`. Also you have not closed few tags properly.

Here you go:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#filevalidity').change(function() {
    var option = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val();
    if (option === "MAX_DOWNLOAD_LIMIT") {

      jQuery('#dlorex').find("input[name='downlimit']").datepicker("destroy");
    }
    if (option === "EXPIRY_DATE") {

      jQuery('#dlorex').find("input[name='downlimit']").datepicker({
        minDate: 1
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="general">
  <table width="100%">

    <tr>
      <td>File Validity:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="filevalidity" id="filevalidity">
          <option value="MAX_DOWNLOAD_LIMIT">Download Limit</option>
          <option value="EXPIRY_DATE">Expiry Date</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dlorex">
      <td>
        <label>Download Limit</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="downlimit" />
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ktjsyfg0/4/

Comment: `jQuery('#dlorex').next('input')` looks for `input` at same level as `tr` which is not the case in your code

Answer (score -1):

$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
  }
});